# How to remove unwanted email address from list of autocomplete suggestions in Gmail "To" field

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-auto-complete

I entered user@example.org but accidentally mispelled the address. then Gmail will most likely save the email for future reference.

However, when you send your email, an email pops up in your Inbox saying "Mail Delivery Notification (Failure)" of the incorrect email address you used. You now notice your mistake, and go and compose a new email with the correct email into your "To" box, but you notice that the incorrect email address comes up as a suggestion! How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) and in the left-side menu click on *Other contacts* (last item from the list). From there, either scroll until you find the respective contact or search for it in the search field. When you find it, click on the three vertical dots in the far-right side and then click on delete.

[image]

Comment: The address is not in Contacts as I never created a record for the person (correct address or not) and is not in Other contacts. It does not appear in any search of my Inbox or my Sent.

Comment: there are NO 3 DOTS in contacts & Most of them are NOT LISTED.